# define method with UInt8 variable

Tags: crystal-lang

I have method with `UInt8` variable:

```
class User
  getter :age

  def initialize(@age : UInt8)
  end
end

user = User.new(30)
```

in this way I get error:

```
no overload matches 'User.new' with type Int32
Overloads are:
 - User.new(age : UInt8)

user = User.new(30)
```

I know that I can initialize Object with `_u8`

```
user = User.new(30_u8)
```

but is there some way to do it automatically without `_u8`?

PS

question related not only to `UInt8`, but to all `Int`s types

Comment: See the issue: [Untyped number literals](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/2995)

Comment: Appears it works these days FWIW...

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
class User
  getter age : UInt8

  def initialize(age : Number)
    @age = age.to_u8
  end
end

user = User.new(30)
```

Comment: yep, I understood it, but it is not right way. In Go-lang, for example, it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot fix it easily.

Try running `puts 1.class` and you will see `Int32`. That means if you type just a number you get `Int32` instance. It cannot be automatically converted to `Uint8` or any other class because types are not converted automatically (as far I know).

Even if they would be converted automatically it is a good practice to be more explicit and code all theese conversions.

In your case create an alias with all numeric formats (read about `Number` or `Int`) and set variable within constructor like `@age = a.to_u8`.

Comment: I see what you meen, but when I declare method's variable `UInt8` it should convert to `uint8`, and if user try use value more/less than `uint8` it just should raise error. That way implemented in `Go`. And I guess it's bug. Maybe in stable version it will be fixed...